# Show that the maximum is reached

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=D(0,1)$.

Let $f  \in \mathcal{O}(D)$ be holomorphic such that  $f'$ is bounded in $D$.

let $g=(1-|z|) |f'(z)|$.

I try to prove that $g$ reaches its maximum in $D$.

$g$ is continuous (holomorphic) and bounded , but is it enough to prove that it reaches a maximum in $D$?

Thank you!

Comment: The datum $f(0)=0$ is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I removed what is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: $g$ is continuous on the closed disc if defined as zero on the boundary. Since the closed disc is compact, the redefined $g$ attains its maximum somewhere on the closed disc. If $f'$ is zero on the open disc, then the maximum of $g$ is zero and it is attained at $z=0$. Otherwise, the maximum is attained in the open unit disc, i.e. by the original $g$.

Comment: @totoro In your last sentence: Otherwise the maximum is attained in the open disk: is this because there must be a compact inside D where the sup |g| is reached because g is holomorphic ?  Otherwise I don't understand why the maximum should be reached in D

Comment: Because on the boundary the new $g$ is zero, and we are assuming that there is a point in the interior, where it is non-zero, and therefore larger than zero.

Comment: But this is in contradiction with the maximum modulus principle. Are you sure that $g$ is holomorphic in $D$?